# How do I modify an environment variable with special characters?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, prompt

My prompt is set to `$P$_CMD>` (with a space at the end). This works great. However, [virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv)'s [activate.bat](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/virtualenv_embedded/activate.bat) has the following line:

```
set PROMPT=(approot) %PROMPT%
```

When I run that command, cmd complains that

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

This did not happen before I changed my prompt. I've tried adding quotation marks (double `"` and single `'`) around `%PROMPT%`, but that doesn't work. How do I modify the prompt, making use of the old value, when the old value contains special characters?

Comment: Note that this problem can be worked around b using `$G` instead of `>` in the prompt. Type `prompt /?` to see all the options.

Comment: As your comment states (you should probably self-answer), you should not be using special characters in the first place. All special characters have a `special code` substitute. It's not a workaround, it's how it's designed to work.

Comment: Do the special code substitutes work for other environment variables?

Comment: No, these are specifically for the prompt. They're only converted when displaying the prompt; they're stored as the code.

Comment: @AndresRiofrio   try set a=>  <-- error.  Try  set a=^>  <-- that works. But then echo %a%  gives an error,  echo "%a%" works but surrounds the whole thing with quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the prompt variable, you should never use special characters. Always use the [`special codes`](https://superuser.com/a/429945/117590) that can be found with `prompt /?` whenever possible.

In response to your comment:

With other variables, you can use [`SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Then refer to the variables with `!`s instead of `%`s.

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the `SETLOCAL command`. When delayed expansion is in effect variables may be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal `%variable_name%`)

Since the variable is expanded at execution time, and the special character `>` (in this case) is only special at parse time, you sidestep the issue entirely.

For example:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set test=World^>
set test2=Hello !test!
```

Note that `^` is the escape character, allowing you to enter special characters (the variable would be stored as `World>`, so unless you do `set test=World^^^>` leading to a stored value of `World^>`, this won't work for your question.

Escaping can get complicated. For example, to set `test2` to the literal `!test!`, you need to use `^^!test^^!`, otherwise you'll just get the value of `test`. If I really need to, I normally just vary the number of escape characters until it works, it's easier than trying to figure out the parsing rules.