# What's the default value of %PROMPT% in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, prompt

I changed the value of `%PROMPT%`, and now [some things](https://superuser.com/questions/429939/how-do-i-modify-an-environment-variable-with-special-characters) aren't working. What's its default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value is `$P$G`.

Possible `special codes` can be displayed with the command `prompt /?`:

```
>prompt /?
Changes the cmd.exe command prompt.

PROMPT [text]

  text    Specifies a new command prompt.

Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:

  $A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
  $D   Current date
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
  $G   > (greater-than sign)
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
  $L   < (less-than sign)
  $N   Current drive
  $P   Current drive and path
  $Q   = (equal sign)
  $S     (space)
  $T   Current time
  $V   Windows version number
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
  $$   $ (dollar sign)

If Command Extensions are enabled the PROMPT command supports
the following additional formatting characters:

  $+   zero or more plus sign (+) characters depending upon the
       depth of the PUSHD directory stack, one character for each
       level pushed.

  $M   Displays the remote name associated with the current drive
       letter or the empty string if current drive is not a network
       drive.
```

The `prompt` environment variable did not appear in the dialog box you mentioned. I found the value through `echo %prompt%`. You should probably delete the environment variable entry if it appears, which should be enough to revert to default. In any case, it should not be in the user variables by default.

My user variables only define `TEMP` and `TMP`.